# Internet seems to be really slow only when connected to wifi

Tags: networking, wireless, broadcom

My internet seems to be really slow only when connected to wifi on my ubuntu box (17.04).The wifi connection in general seems to work really fast on my other macs and windows machines,what could be the problem here?

I have tried disabling the powermanagement for my wireless card as mentioned in many tutorials, and my drivers are installed.

here is a dump of my lspci command : 
https://paste.ubuntu.com/24909958/

Network diagnostics logs : http://paste.ubuntu.com/24917418/

I also got a few timeouts : logs here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24917424/

here is my kernel driver : 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/24909975/

iwconfig and ifconfig logs: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24910082/

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thanks for the reply,I have edited my question with the necessary logs.Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you please try the driver listed for your wireless adapter in https://askubuntu.com/a/60395/175814? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thanks a lot,installing the right driver worked.Thanks for pointing me to the right answer